# What is the equivalent regex expression \b written using ^ and $?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, word-boundary

How can I rewrite my anchor to be more general and correct in all situations? I have understood that using `\b` as an anchor is not optimal because it is implementation-dependent.

My goal is to match some type of word in a text file. For my question, the word to match is not of importance.

Assume `\b` is the word boundary anchor and a word character is [a-zA-Z0-9_]
I constructed two anchors, one for the left and one for the right side of the regex. Notice how I handle the underscore, as I don't want it to be a word character when I read my text file.

- `(?<=\b|_)` positive lookbehind
- `(?=\b|_)` positive lookahead

What would be the equivalent anchor constructs but using the more general caret `^` and `$` dollar sign to get the same effect?

Comment: I'll bet that any regexp engine that has lookarounds also has `\b`. Lookarounds are newer and not available as widely.

Comment: All regex symbols are implementation-dependent, including `*`, `|`, `\ ` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*The OP did not specify which regex language they are using. This answer uses Perl's regex language, but the final solution should be easy to translate into other languages. Also, I use whitespace as if the `x` flag was provided, but that is also easily adjusted.*]

---

With the help of a comment made by the OP, the following is my understanding of the question:

> I have something like `\b\w+\b`, but I want to exclude `_` the definition of a word.

You can use the following:

```
(?<! [^\W_] ) [^\W_]+ (?! [^\W_] )
```

An explanation follows.

---

`\b` is equivalent to `(?: (?<!\w)(?=\w) | (?<=\w)(?!\w) )`.

`\b \w+ \b` is therefore equivalent to `(?<!\w) \w+ (?!\w)` (after simplification).

So now we just need a pattern that matches everything `\w` matches but `_`. There are a few approaches that can be taken.

- Set difference: `(?[ \w - [_] ])`
- Look-ahead: `(?!_)\w`
- Look-behind: `\w(?<!_)`
- Double negation: `[^\W_]`

Even though it's the least readable, I'm going to use the last one since it's the best supported.

We now have

```
(?<! [^\W_] ) [^\W_]+ (?! [^\W_] )
```

Comment: as I said in the post, the word is not important for my question. For example, I have this regex (?<=\b|_)sUs[^\W_]*(?=\b|_) which matches a word with the prefix sUs. The question was, can I replace the anchor expressions (?<=\b|_) and (?=\b|_)  with some other expression that uses ^ and $ symbols AND does not use \b,  but achieves the exact same result

Comment: Not using `\b` for no reason is stupid. (Implementation-dependent is not a reason, since `\w` is just as implementation-dependent.) However, `(?<=\b|_)` is a variable-length lookbehind, and that's not well supported. You could use 
`(?<! [^\W_] ) sUs [^\W_]*`. Answer updated.

Comment: I tested your updated answer against my text file, and it appears to be equivalent to my initial expression, and it indeed refrains from using \b. The idea about ^ and $ is a misunderstanding on OP (me) part. I guess my whole text file is counted as one large string, and ^ matches the beginning, and $ the end.

Comment: If you think `^` and `$` aren't implementation-specific, you're wrong. They vary more than `\b`

Answer (score 1):

You can match a non-word character or the beginning/end anchor:

```
(?:^|\W)(\w+)(?:\W|$)
```

If you want to select something other than a single word, replace `\w+` with the pattern you're looking for. Capture group 1 will contain what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks ok at the surface, but impractical in practice because it doesn't allow you to grab more all words, and when's the last time you wanted one arbitrary word from a string? This is easily fixed by replacing `(^|\W)(\w+)(\W|$)` with `(\w+)`.  /// There's also the issue that this answer doesn't identify any of a slew of other problems `\w+` has at identifying words.

Comment: I've updated the answer to say that the capture group can be practically any pattern.

Comment: I meant you couldn't use the pattern to find all words (or whatever's in the middle) because you're consuming both edges instead of using (zero-width) anchors like in the OP.

Comment: Of course. Avoiding that requires using lookarounds. But as I mentioned above, I doubt there are any engines without word boundary that have lookarounds.